# Azure Databricks - getting exception while connecting to elastic search

Tags: azure, scala, elasticsearch, azure-databricks

Imported "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.13:8.1.3" in to Azure Databricks cluster

Databricks Runtime Version: 13.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.4.0, Scala 2.12)

```
%scala

val reader = spark.read
      .format( "org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .option( "spark.es.nodes.wan.only", "false")
      .option( "spark.es.port",  "9243")
      .option( "spark.es.net.ssl",  "false")
      .option( "spark.es.nodes", "http://mydeployment.eastus.azure.elastic-cloud.com")
      .option("spark.es.resource",  "flights")      
      .option("spark.es.net.http.auth.user", "xxxx")
      .option("spark.es.net.http.auth.pass", "xxxx")
      .option("spark.es.index.read.missing.as.empty", "true")
  .option("spark.es.mapping.date.rich","false")
  .option("spark.es.nodes.discovery", "true")
  .option("spark.es.nodes.resolve.hostname", "false")
     
val df = reader.load("flights").limit(10)
df.show()
```

Getting exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
```

Elastic Cloud version:
[image]

What would be reason & how to resolve this issue?